# carousel showing only one card when put it in partial view?

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have created carousel using following link
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/
But when  put it  into partial view its not looking good, why? Only one card shown on carosoul
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is related that the Bootstrap reference or the MDBootstrap reference (such as: CSS or JavaScript file) not load successfully.

I have create a sample using the CDN reference, it works well on my side, please check it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&amp;display=swap">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.19.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/css/compiled-addons-4.19.1.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mdbootstrap.com/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/css/mdb-plugins-gathered.min.css">
<style></style>

<partial name="~/Views/Home/testPartialView.cshtml" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.19.1/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.19.1/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.19.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/api/snippets/static/download/MDB-Pro_4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/js/bundles/4.19.1/compiled-addons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/wp-content/themes/mdbootstrap4/js/plugins/mdb-plugins-gathered.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script><div class="hiddendiv common"></div>
```

In the Partial View, I use the Multi-item carousel sample code from [this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/#multi-item-carousel).

**Edit**:

To display the page number in the carousel indicators at the bottom of the carousel. As a workaround, you could set the carousel indicators item's background-image property, code as below (based on the [multi-item-carousel sample code](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/carousel/#multi-item-carousel)):

```
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="0" 
            style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fn7MP.png') !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="1" 
            style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE3mt.png') !important; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#multi-item-example" data-slide-to="2" 
            style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/T90QU.png') !important;  
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;" class=""></li>
    </ol>
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: I want carousel  which has  pagination.

Comment: @teju can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have used this link     https://www.codeply.com/go/EIOtI7nkP8/bootstrap-carousel-with-multiple-cards,    to create cards , i want  number for pagination

Comment: Do you mean the carousel indicators at the bottom of the carousel, you could check [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y75c5.png)? If that is the case, please check the document samples.

Comment: @teju Please check my Edit, I also try to directly add page numbers in the carousel indicators item, but the number doesn't display. So, as a workaround, you could set the carousel indicators item's background-image property. If you still want to [Custom Carousel Indicators](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/custom-carousel-indicators/), you could post this issue on [MDBootstrap forum](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/)